# Could i checkout another branch while current branch pushing processed?

Tags: git, github

GIT. When I already clicked(or executed the command in the console) "push", can I switch to another branch?

Comment: just wait......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**. Pushed or not, **commits are branch-related**.

*You may need more steps (a "rebase") only if you need to move local commits to another branch, which is not your case.*

Answer (score -1):

use the git worktree.

## ***`git worktree`***

```
git worktree add <second path>
```

will create another folder on your computer which allow you to work on different branch **simultaneously** so you dont have to push and can work on multiple branches and pushonly when needed.

[image]